# Error in using by in R

Tags: r, gam

I'm new to R and started using it to implement a gam model. I've been following this [tutorial](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gam.models.html) examples and R keeps throwing an error when I try to use by. I really have no idea what's wrong and would appreciate it if anybody can suggest something.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
    >require(mgcv)
    >set.seed(10)
    ## simulate date from y = f(x2)*x1 + error
    >dat <- gamSim(3,n=400)
    Continuous `by' variable example
    >b<-gam(y ~ s(x2,by=x1),data=dat)
    Error in s(x2, by = x1) : unused argument (by = x1)
```

[image]

Additional information: R version = 3.3.1 (2013-06-21)
                        OS = Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Code*

```
require(mgcv)
set.seed(10)
## simulate date from y = f(x2)*x1 + error
dat <- gamSim(3,n=400)

b <- gam(y ~ s(x2,by=x1),data=dat)
b
```

*Result*

> Continuous `by' variable example
>
> Family: gaussian  Link function: identity
>
> Formula: y ~ s(x2, by = x1)
>
> Estimated degrees of freedom:
>   9.2  total = 10.2
>
> GCV score: 4.518245

Please start a fresh R session and see if you get the same error. Also, please check your version of `mgcv` and make sure it's up to date.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick answer. However I didn't type 'Continuous `by' variable example' or 'Error in s(x2, by = x1) : unused argument (by = x1)' (which is what I think you are referring to?). Those two were the messages generated by R console when I type the code. Sorry about the ambiguity in the question, I've updated it with an image.

Comment: @words_of_wisdom Thanks for the clarification. The code runs fine for me. Have you made any changes to the environment or anything? I have the same version of R and OS as you...  Please start a fresh R session and see if you get the same error. Also, please check your version of `mgcv` and make sure it's up to date.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I haven't made any changes at all. Just installed R yesterday actually and have no idea what's wrong :(

Comment: @words_of_wisdom What version of mgcv are you running? I can see in the screenshot that a lot of code had been run beforehand based on the scroll bar, so please be sure to start a fresh session of R and then try running the code in my answer first thing.

Comment: Hi, I just restarted the OS and started R again which seems to have solved the problem. I've marked your answer as the correct answer. Thanks again!